# Putting spaces between two \arrowvert to indicate cardinality of a group

Tags: math-mode, spacing

How to put spaces between two vertical lines in Latex for e.g typing the usual notation of cardinality of a group ?

Comment: `|\quad|` or `|~|` or any other kind of hspace. `\hspace{3pt}`.

Comment: Usually I type something like: `... where $|\cdot|$ denotes the cardinality of a set`.

Comment: I think it's better to type $\lvert\cdot\rvert$.

Comment: @HenriMenke Please, make an answer also explaining why some symbol such as a middle dot is needed.

Comment: @Bernard The problem with `\lvert\cdot\rvert` is the spacing, to get what in my opinion is better you should write `\lvert{}\cdot{}\rvert` which in some cases you avoid using just `|\cdot|`.

Comment: You're right but inserting a pair of {} makes spacing around  \cdot that of a binary operator, which is too much in my opinion. Writing \lvert\mkip2mu\cdot\mskip2mu\rvert would be better, to my taste.

Answer (score 5):

Not putting a `\cdot` between the delimiters of the argument will lead to an ambiguous meaning. Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\begin{document}
\ldots where $|\cdot|$ denotes the cardinality of a set\ldots
\[ \aleph = |A| \]

\ldots where $|\ |$ denotes the cardinality of a set\ldots
\[ \aleph = |\ |A \mbox{ or } \aleph = A|\ | \mbox{ or } \aleph = |A| \mbox{?} \]

\ldots where $||$ denotes the cardinality of a set\ldots

\ldots where $\|$ is the delimiter for the 2-norm\ldots
\[ \| v \| \equiv \sqrt{\langle v, v\rangle} \]
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: I'd use `\text` not `\mbox` also, I'd make a `\blank` macro to hold the blank arg instead of writing `\cdot` all the time. Even better I'd make `\Card` and `\norm` macros that has the empty argument marker build in, this is very easy using `mathtools` and `\ifblank` from `etoolbox`

Comment: @daleif Of course, you are right. Writing macros for that purpose is much better, also using `\text` is preferable to `\mbox`, but you need `amsmath`/`mathtools` for that and I wanted to keep the example as minimal as possible.

Comment: Well, I'd better educate users to use amsmath...

Answer (score 2):

Just to complete it all

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{mathtools,etoolbox}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\Card[1]\lvert\rvert{
  \ifblank{#1}{{-}}{#1}
}
\begin{document}
where $\Card{}$ denotes the cardinality of a set:
\[ \aleph = \Card{A} \]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another variant of [Henri's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156006/16967) using `\dots`.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
where $\lvert\dots\rvert$ denotes the cardinality of a set:
\[ \aleph = \lvert A\rvert \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]